# Django - cache page on server but NOT on client

Tags: django, caching

I have a few (almost) static pages on my website, I use @cache_page to cache the entire response.

```
@cache_page(99999)
def my_view(...)
```

The problem is that this automatically adds the header "max-age=99999" to the response and I do NOT want the client to do any caching.

How can I cache entire HTML responses on the server without allowing client caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`never_cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache) decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
@cache_page(99999)
def my_view(request):
    # ...
```

Comment: This appears to work at first but I think it will stop adding new items to the cache. In `django/middelware/cache.py` on line 91 (3.10) there is a line that prevents it from storing to server side cache if the header cache is set to private.